# AWS SES Sending Email Sender Identity Verification Problem

Tags: amazon-web-services, go, amazon-ses

I'm sending emails via AWS Simple Email Service but I have a problem. In the email I sent there is a verification problem. [image]  Unfortunately, it is bad reputation for our customer. We're using SES to send important emails about payment and subscriptions. That's why we have to make our customers feel safe. Is there anyone who knows why it happens or how I solve it? Thank's in advance.

Comment: Have you checked what is behind the "Click here to learn more" link?

Comment: of course but customers won't want to do it. I have to solve this problem on my own. For example if I use CompanyName-info@company.com it's okay but CompanyName <info@company.com> doesn't work properly.

Comment: Have you verified your email?

Comment: This is because the receiver cannot verify the senders identity, you need to read [Email Authentication Methods](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/ses/latest/dg/email-authentication-methods.html) and choose an authentication methods that suits you best. Good luck!